# Static UITableView Cell Property Modification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, static

I have a static `UITableView` setup in my storyboard. I have subclassed some cells and added this property:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label;`

I also have code to add the label to my cell in the `layoutSubviews` method. My label shows in my cell without an issue. I can see the label saying 'PLACEHOLDER' but it is not updated to say the text I set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I have the following:

```
APInfoTableViewCell *cell = (APInfoTableViewCell*)[super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell.label setText@"Hello World"];
```

However, this will not update the text in my label. The label is actually nil.

EDIT:

Here is the full code...

`UITableViewCell` Subclass:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *infoLabel;

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self initUI];
}

-(void)initUI
{
    //add long press to show info label
    _infoLabel = [UILabel new];
    [_infoLabel setText:@"PLACEHOLDER"];
    [_infoLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:10.0f]];
    [_infoLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [_infoLabel setTextColor:[UIColor apText]];
    [_infoLabel setAlpha:1.0f];
    [_infoLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self addSubview:_infoLabel];

    NSArray *infoConstraintH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-40-[infoLbl]-40-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{ @"infoLbl" : _infoLabel }];
    [self addConstraints:infoConstraintH];
    NSArray *infoConstraintV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[infoLbl]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{ @"infoLbl" : _infoLabel }];
    [self addConstraints:infoConstraintV];
}
```

`ViewController`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    APInfoTableViewCell *cell = (APInfoTableViewCell*)[super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell.infoLabel setText@"Hello World"];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you show full code??

Comment: add the code in your layoutSubviews

Comment: Updated with more code.

Comment: Why you are creating label in layout subview?

Comment: Where should I be? I want to create it in the subclass so I can reuse it. I don't want that code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Are you using Storyboard?

Comment: Yes but this specific `UILabel` I would not like to have to reproduce in a large number of cells. Each cell is uniquely made in my storyboard and then I want to overlay this additional label on all of them. Hence the subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using storyboard, and you don't want to add IB outlet then call your `initUI` method from `awakeFromNib` method. 
If you are not using storyboard implement `- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` method and call it from there.

awakeFromNib method is called once the cell(or any UIView subclass) is instantiated from nib(either from storyboard or from xib). And its called only once in the lifetime of the view

Note: This will not get called if you are creating a view subclass programmatically.

As per documentation

> Subclasses can override this method as needed to perform more precise layout of their subviews. You should override this method only if the autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior you want. You can use your implementation to set the frame rectangles of your subviews directly.

That means, use this method to do any additional lay outing of already added. This method is called when some frame/autolayout constraint changes happens.

Comment: Did the trick! Thanks, silly of me to put in the `layoutSubviews` I guess.

Comment: @JoshKahane Updated my answer to explain more about scenario

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a new cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns visible instantiated cells in the table view. As you aren't instantiating your cells anywhere there are no cells in the table view, so `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns `nil`.

Additionally `layoutSubviews` is called **a lot** and is called late. You **should not** rely on it to initialise your label. As it stands your cell will keep adding additional labels when ever `layoutSubviews` is called! The designated initialiser is the place to add that `initUI` code (as the name implies ). If your `UITableViewCell` subclass doesn't use a XIB/Storyboard for its view, `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` is the designated initialiser. (Otherwise it is `initWithCoder:` or `awakeFromNib`)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. However I preferably need to use a static UITableView, surely your suggestion would only be relevant to dynamic tables?